# Failure to recognize passed type

Tags: c#, function, object, types

I am given the error

> "The type or namespace name 'passedType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

on the two references to passedType inside the function. Why does it not recognize the "passedType" variable?

```
public bool ObjectIsInHighlightedList(object thing, Type passedType)
{
  foreach (object obj in _highlightedList)
  {
     if (obj is passedType && thing == (passedType)obj)
        return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: passedType is of type Type. So your obj object should be cast as Type.

Comment: Do you always know `passedType` statically?  If so, you should change this method to a generic method, then you can test `obj is T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) method.

```
public bool ObjectIsInHighlightedList(object thing, Type passedType)
{
  foreach (object obj in _highlightedList)
  {
     if (passedType.IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType()) && (object)thing == obj)
        return true;
  }
}
```

This would actually be a good scenario for a generic method, however:

```
public bool ObjectIsInHighlightedList<T>(object thing)
{
  foreach (object obj in _highlightedList)
  {
     if (obj is T && thing == (T)obj)
        return true;
  }
}
```